# How can I display images like a deck of cards (stack) sort of like Tinder?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, stack

As of now, I can display an image the user uploads onto the browser like so.

```
if (redirectToStackAfterPhotoSubmit) {
        return (
            <Stack
                imagesOnStack={this.state.url || 'http://via.placeholder.com/400x300'}
                alt="Uploaded Images"
                height="300"
                Width="400"
            />
        );
    }
```

But this time, I want the user to have the ability to go the next or previous picture with the click of a button.  I'm aware my attempt is trying to make a list, I only made it this way just to get idea of what I'm working with.

Directly below is my attempt, What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Here's `Upload.js` (didn't post everything because it's a large file)

```
     this.state = {
           url: '',
           picture: [],
           selectedPictureIndex: 0
        };

     render() {
        const redirectToStackAfterPhotoSubmit = this.state.redirectToStackAfterPhotoSubmit;

        const { picture } = this.state;

        const picList = picture.map(pic => {
            return(
                <li key={pic.id}>{this.state.url[pic]}</li>
            );
        });

        if (redirectToStackAfterPhotoSubmit) {
            return (
                <Stack
                    imagesOnStack={picList || 'http://via.placeholder.com/400x300'}
                    alt="Uploaded Images"
                    height="300"
                    Width="400"
                />
            );
        }
    }
```

Here's `Stack.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Stack extends Component {
    toggleNext() {
        console.log("clicked toggleNext()");
        if(this.state.selectedPicture === this.state.picture.length - 1) {
            return;
        }

        this.setState(prevState => ({
            selectedPicture: prevState.selectedIndex + 1
        }));
    }

    togglePrevious() {
        console.log("clicked togglePrevious()");
        if(this.state.selectedPicture === 0) {
            return;
        }

        this.setState(prevState => ({
            selectedPicture: prevState.selectedPicture - 1
        }));
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <img src={this.props.imagesOnStack} alt=""/>
                <button onClick={this.toggleNext}>Next</button>
                <button onClick={this.togglePrevious}>Prev</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Stack;
```

Answer (score 0):

For react native, here is a npm package that uses the swipe deck: react-native-swipe-card.

Github Repos: https://github.com/EQuimper/MyOwnChallenge-RnMovieTinder Packages: https://github.com/meteor-factory/react-native-tinder-swipe-cards

For React, you can use react-swipe-card

```
import Cards, { Card } from 'react-swipe-card'


const data = ['Alexandre', 'Thomas', 'Lucien']

const Wrapper = () => {
  return (
      <Cards onEnd={action('end')} className='master-root'>
        {data.map(item => 
          <Card 
            onSwipeLeft={action('swipe left')} 
            onSwipeRight={action('swipe right')}>
            <h2>{item}</h2>
          </Card>
        )}
      </Cards>
  )
}
```

Comment: For react, you can use the react-swipe-card